Does BSC support Cancun?
I am trying to deploy a smart contract on a Cancun EVM usage target remix. However, several functions of the BSC-721 smart contract that I created experienced the error "invalid opcode: MCOPY". Does BSC not support the Cancun version of the compiler yet?

BNB Smart Chain does not support Cancun.
Binance does not co-ordinate or work with Ethereum developer community, but has its independent roadmap.

Yes, I think the BSC chain doesn't support Cancun yet. Hard fork targets: Testnet (17th April 2024), Mainnet (15th June 2024)
